# possible unique combinations between between two arrays(of different size) in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, python-3.4, python-itertools

```
arr1=['One','Two','Five'],arr2=['Three','Four']
```

like `itertools.combinations(arr1,2)` gives us 
`('OneTwo','TwoFive','OneFive')`
 
I was wondering is there any way applying this to two different arrays.?I mean for arr1 and arr2.

`Output should be OneThree,OneFour,TwoThree,TwoFour,FiveThree,FiveFour`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating all unique pair permutations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169122/generating-all-unique-pair-permutations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

From the doc, it does this:

```
product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
```

Sample code:

```
>>> x = itertools.product(arr1, arr2)
>>> for i in x: print i
('One', 'Three')
('One', 'Four')
('Two', 'Three')
('Two', 'Four')
('Five', 'Three')
('Five', 'Four')
```

To combine them:

```
# This is the full code
import itertools

arr1 = ['One','Two','Five']
arr2 = ['Three','Four']

combined = ["".join(x) for x in itertools.product(arr1, arr2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you wanted is `OneThree,OneFour,TwoThree,TwoFour,FiveThree,FiveFour` then a double `for` loop will do the trick for you:

```
>>> for x in arr1:
        for y in arr2:
            print(x+y)


OneThree
OneFour
TwoThree
TwoFour
FiveThree
FiveFour
```

Or if you want the result in a list:

```
>>> [x+y for x in arr1 for y in arr2]
['OneThree', 'OneFour', 'TwoThree', 'TwoFour', 'FiveThree', 'FiveFour']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
["".join(v) for v in itertools.product(arr1, arr2)]
#results in 
['OneThree', 'OneFour', 'TwoThree', 'TwoFour', 'FiveThree', 'FiveFour']
```