# Automatically calculate delta e of different LAB values

Tags: python, colors, cielab, colormath

```
from colormath.color_diff import delta_e_cie2000
from colormath.color_objects import LabColor

color1 = LabColor(lab_l=80.4569, lab_a=2.1034, lab_b=53.0929)
color2 = LabColor(lab_l=88.8133, lab_a=-0.9955, lab_b=25.3040)
color3 = LabColor(lab_l=84.7402, lab_a=-0.4937, lab_b=38.7848)
color4 = LabColor(lab_l=81.2277, lab_a=1.3795, lab_b=45.8783)
color5 = LabColor(lab_l=84.0132, lab_a=-0.4293, lab_b=34.9080)
color6 = LabColor(lab_l=83.2528, lab_a=0.5219, lab_b=42.0932)
color7 = LabColor(lab_l=83.3647, lab_a=-0.5631, lab_b=39.7694)

A = delta_e_cie2000(color1, color2), delta_e_cie2000(color1, color3), delta_e_cie2000(color1, color4), delta_e_cie2000(color1, color5), delta_e_cie2000(color1, color6), delta_e_cie2000(color1, color7)
B = delta_e_cie2000(color2, color3), delta_e_cie2000(color2, color4), delta_e_cie2000(color2, color5), delta_e_cie2000(color2, color6), delta_e_cie2000(color2, color7)
C = delta_e_cie2000(color3, color4), delta_e_cie2000(color3, color5), delta_e_cie2000(color3, color6), delta_e_cie2000(color3, color7)
D = delta_e_cie2000(color4, color5), delta_e_cie2000(color4, color6), delta_e_cie2000(color4, color7)
E = delta_e_cie2000(color5, color6), delta_e_cie2000(color5, color7)
F = delta_e_cie2000(color6, color7)


print(A)
print(B)
print(C)
print(D)
print(E)
print(F)
```

With this script I calculate the delta e between each color. It works fine, but it's a lot of work when I have to add another color. So my question is: is there a function to compare each color with eachother at the same time?

Comment: I think you are asking: how to get all possible pair permutation from elements in one set? [Then it will be trivial to calculate the deltaE] -- so, something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169122/generating-all-unique-pair-permutations?

Comment: Yes it is somthing like that, but how can I implement this in my script?